# How do I do Android unit testing in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I am new to Android.  I tried googling for a solution for how to do Unit testing for Android in IntelliJ and found http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Creating+Unit+Tests.  What I am trying to achieve is I have begun to write a simple Twitter Client and would like to write some unit tests for it  Initially when trying just to write a test class within src I got "Java.lang.RuntimeException - Stub!", and understand from looking at another SO post that this is because you cannot run a Unit test within the Android application itself (i.e. you need to create a test module).

However, when I open IntelliJ 13 I can't see the option to create a test module.  All I see if I go to New Project - Android is:

Gradle: Android Module,
Application Module,
Empty Module,
Library Module

with no option to create a test module.  Am I best off just choosing Empty Module and trying to create a test module from there?

Comment: Put the cursor on the class you want to test and press `ctrl+shift+T` in Windows or `cmd+shift+T` in Mac.

Comment: Try the Android Unit and Functional tests using the Instrumentation Framework. It's documentation is now clearer than earlier.

Comment: @alfasin When I try and run the test as you suggested I get java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!.

Comment: @JaVAndroid I'm guessing you mean Instrumentation Framework as detailed in http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTesting/article.html#androidtesting_instrumentation.  Will I be able to run this within src without getting the Stub! exception?

Comment: Actually scrap that, I've read more though the tutorial and it explains how to run the test case as a separate project.  Many thanks for your help.